# I can’t get Kivy to work in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, kivy

I’ve installed Kivy with Python and when I check the version it confirms that it’s there.  But when I try to use files in VS, I get the message “kivy files require # kivy”.

I’ve searched for solutions to this but I can’t find anything.

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem early on. What worked for me is as follows:

- Going to Terminal or Command Prompt and typing
  `python3 -m pip install kivy`
  or
  `python3`
  then
  `>>> pip install kivy`
- I used another IDE called Mu Code (for Python) and tried it there. If it works for one application, it should work for all of them. Some other applications (like Mu) have a feature called the REPL, a read-evaluate-print-loop, that works like a python version of the terminal.
- Also, be sure to check that you have correctly installed the latest version of Python. As of time of writing, the most current Python version is 3.10.5. You can download it from https://www.python.org/downloads/.
- You can also try using the Python IDLE.

You can check if it's installed by using `python3 -m kivy` at the command line.

In the end, what worked for me was a lot of troubleshooting.

Hope that was helpful.